# Adding another cell to tableview when done editing textview inside cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would just like to preface this with the fact that I don't use storyboards.

I have a tableview with multiple sections that are filled with tableViewcells I have created programmatically. These custom cells include a textfield with some placeholder text. What I want the user to be able to do is to tap on the textfield, type their entry, and then hit "Enter" to dismiss the keyboard and then create a new cell underneath the cell they just edited. This is very similar to the behaviour that happens in the reminders app.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to access the tableview's data model (an array) and figuring out which section that cell is in, adding the new string to the array, and then adding another dumby cell that has the placeholder text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all you have to create a way to communicate between your cell and view controller. 
You can use delegate pattern or callbacks for this.
For example:

```
final class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Local variables
    var callback: ((_ text: String) -> Void)?

    // MARK: - Lyfecycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to call our callback:

```
extension TextFieldCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        callback?(textField.text!)
        return true
    }
}
```

Great! Now we send our string from cell to controller!

Example of code for your view controller(simplified version):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Local variables
    var titles = ["Hello", "world"]
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let textFieldCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell

        textFieldCell.textField.placeholder = titles[indexPath.row]
        textFieldCell.callback = { [weak self] newTitle in // don't forget about memory leaks
            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            // calculating index path for new row
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)

            // appending a new row in table view
            self.titles.append(newTitle)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }

        return textFieldCell
    }
}
```

Comment: Few things which I noticed: For callback parameter type use just type, not name of parameter `((String) -> Void)?`. Next, ` `self` ` could be `self`, compiler knows that you declare it in local scope. Last, animation type is of type `UITableView.RowAnimation`, you can use instead of  `UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic` just `.automatic`

Comment: Yes, I know, but this was all done for better understanding for less experienced developers.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I implemented your solution and it worked flawlessly; I just have some questions as to why it works.

1) Why does the callback variable have a weird format? My guess is that it's a closure.
2) I'm not sure why the callback is called in the cellforRowAt delegate method instead of the didSelectRowAt method.
3) Why use `self`?

Comment: Glad to hear! 1) Yes, callback it’s just a closure. You can send any data throw this. 2) didSelectRowAt will be called when you tapped on your cell. You set a closure for textField callback in cellForRow method, so it is called there. 3) If you use class variables in any closure ypu have to write [weak self] to avoid memory leaks. You can read about memory managment and strong references to understand this. Good luck in your learning!